# C++11: returning an array

Tags: c++, collections, stl, c++11, containers

I'm currently facing an interesting situation with STL containers.
I have a method that should return different static arrays of objects depending on a parameter. Said objects are of type array<SomeClass, *_*>.

The reason for the underscore is that they are not all arrays of the same size. Since array is so neatly wrapped and the sizes of the arrays don't change, I was hoping not to be forced into converting the arrays into vectors, for not only is the initialization very neat right now, but I also find array to be the exact structure I want, and a resizable one would be overhead and overkill.

Any chance I can achieve what I want? If not, is there any cleaner solution than using vectors?

Comment: Your question is unclear to me... Is your method some kind of a template function? Could you show us some context by including code?

Comment: Consider that much like `int[3]`, `std::array<int, 3>` has its size as part of its type. And a given function has one and only one return type. (Keeping in mind that function templates are not functions but the template functions they 'generate' are.) Hopefully this should help you decide what to use.

Answer (score 2):

Can the size of the return array be calculated at compile-time based on the arguments?  If so, then you can use templates to provide the right value for `_`.  E.g., if the return array is the same length as some argument array, then you could do something like:

```
template<int N>
array<SomeClass, N> myFunc(array<Foo, N> someArg);
```

Or if you'll always know the correct size of the return array (at compile time) at the site where you call it, you could do:

```
template<int N>
array<SomeClass, N> myFunc();
```

And call it as:

```
array<SomeClass, 5> = myFunc<5>();
```

If not, then you'll probably have to use vectors.

Comment: My arrays are statically initialized elsewhere and the size of the desired return value is unknown at the call site even at runtime, otherwise I could have also used something dirty such as returning a pointer to a C-style array. Guess I'll resort to vectors

Answer (score 0):

You always have the option of writing an `array_view<T>` class that can act as a reference to `array<T,N>` for any `N`.